# Does jQuerys .append(element) method auto-clone the element?

Tags: jquery, clone

When using `.append(someHTMLElement)` on a jQuery multiselection, does jQuery clone the element to append automatically?

Example:

```
var newElement = $("<p>Some text</p>");
var myElements = $(".multiselector").append(newElement);
```

Does this add `newElement` to **all** of the elements contained in `myElements`?

Comment: Have you tried running it? Just make a fiddle and create a test to get your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/z5xJC/

Comment: Yes it does. The `newElement` will be appened to all `myElements`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

> The .append() method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection

So yes it **copies** to **all** selected elements.